# Ansible not setting Postgres User Password

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, ansible

I'm using Ansible to provision a virtual machine started with Vagrant. I've used both the (preferred) VMware provider and VirtualBox to test, and am getting the same result with each.

I am using the following set of tasks in order to try and create a database called `so`, with and a user `django` with access. However, the database password doesn't appear to be getting set. If I manually set this I can connect, if I try beforehand I always get `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "django"`.

I have posted the relevant section of the Ansible configuration below, and the relevant section of the debug below that (`ansible.verbose = "vvv"` in vagrant configuration).

```
# Create Prostgres DB
- hosts: all
  sudo: True
  sudo_user: postgres

  vars:
    dbname: so
    dbuser: django
    dbpassword: 4967bKzCegrPxVH4tGgQe6kFn232t7KiFDXfedVi

  tasks: 
  - name: Ensure database exists
    postgresql_db: name={{ dbname }}

  - name: Ensure DB user has access to the DB
    postgresql_user: db={{ dbname }} name={{ dbuser }} password={{ dbpassword }} priv=ALL state=present

  # Leave user with ability to create databases. This prividge should be 
  # removed for production, but is required for running tests. 
    postgresql_user: name={{ dbuser }} role_attr_flags=NOSUPERUSER,CREATEDB
```

Verbose output:

```
TASK: [Ensure DB user has access to the DB] *********************************** 
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/danielsgroves/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile=/Users/danielsgroves/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/ansible-1387481596.93-132175356393082 && chmod a+rx /tmp/ansible-1387481596.93-132175356393082 && echo /tmp/ansible-1387481596.93-132175356393082'"]
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE postgresql_user name=django role_attr_flags=NOSUPERUSER,CREATEDB
<127.0.0.1> PUT /var/folders/2j/n8ng8fdd5gj125w5zswg9kj00000gn/T/tmpvnrb37 TO /tmp/ansible-1387481596.93-132175356393082/postgresql_user
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/danielsgroves/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile=/Users/danielsgroves/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', "/bin/sh -c 'chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-1387481596.93-132175356393082/postgresql_user'"]
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/danielsgroves/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile=/Users/danielsgroves/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', '/bin/sh -c \'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=isnxrvycjudgazbgyciehbcpiiswfczx] password: " -u postgres /bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-isnxrvycjudgazbgyciehbcpiiswfczx; /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-1387481596.93-132175356393082/postgresql_user\'"\'"\'\'']
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['ssh', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/danielsgroves/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile=/Users/danielsgroves/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '127.0.0.1', "/bin/sh -c 'rm -rf /tmp/ansible-1387481596.93-132175356393082/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"]
ok: [server] => {"changed": false, "user": "django"}
```

Comment: Interestingly this seems to work on a physical box, just not on a Vagrant VM. Will investigate further when I get a minute.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The same command does however work in a different provisioner which is being used against a production box hosted with Digital Ocean.

Comment: See @eadmundo updated answer below. The last tasks of yours has two actions. Only the last action is executed, the first one is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The final task in that playbook will not be run by ansible - it doesn't have a hyphen in front of the module name. Change it to either:

```yaml
- postgresql_user:
    name: "{{ dbuser }}"
    role_attr_flags: "NOSUPERUSER,CREATEDB"
```

or (I prefer to name all tasks)

```yaml
- name: Set roles for DB user
  postgresql_user:
    name: "{{ dbuser }}"
    role_attr_flags: "NOSUPERUSER,CREATEDB"
```

and you should then be able to login as the django user with

```
$ psql -U django -h localhost so
```

Without any roles set, the user can't login. I think that the 'LOGIN' role must be implicit in the roles that are specified there, although I haven't confirmed that in the PostgreSQL docs.

Comment: This question is asking about how to do this with ansible, not the command line.  Could you provide an ansible task to add the host?

Comment: The answer is correct. Run `ansible-doc postgresql_user` for examples.